# Youtube iframe not showing in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, youtube-api

I have an iframe within the html string,

```
<iframe class='iframeClass' src="https://www.youtube.com/{some_ID}" frameborder=0 width=564 height=347 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 hspace=0 vspace=0 scrolling=no frameborder=0></iframe>
```

this works in a browser but not in my `UIWebView`(in the webview it is just blank where the iframe should be).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid your video URL is not valid. Write the following code into your viewDidLoad:

> ```
> NSString *embedHTML = @"<iframe class='iframeClass' src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/rOPI5LDo7mg\" frameborder=0 width=564 height=347 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 hspace=0 vspace=0 scrolling=no frameborder=0></iframe>";
> [self.webview loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
> ```